# Lambda Python function unable to write to CloudWatch

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to push some custom sample metrics to Cloudwatch from a lambda function using the code below, but it times out, even with a timeout limit of 30 seconds. Just to be sure, I set full CloudWatch permissions to the lambda function, but to no avail. Any ideas what could cause this?

```
import boto3
import random
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    cloudwatch = boto3.client('cloudwatch')
    cloudwatch.put_metric_data(
        MetricData = [
            {
                'MetricName': 'KPIs',
                'Dimensions': [
                    {
                        'Name': 'PURCHASES_SERVICE',
                        'Value': 'CoolService'
                    },
                    {
                        'Name': 'APP_VERSION',
                        'Value': '1.0'
                    },
                ],
                'Unit': 'None',
                'Value': random.randint(1, 500)
            },
        ],
        Namespace = 'TestMetrics'
    )
```

Comment: Are you running lambda inside VPC?

Comment: `'Value': random.randint(1, 500)` - this must be float - not int

Comment: Yes, the Lambda is inside a VPC. However, I tried a new function, same code, but without a VPC, and it still times out.

Comment: to be frank, I am able to run the exact code with and without VPC configuration perfectly fine, maybe you can print the response after calling the put_metric_data function. Wrote [something similar](https://github.com/toddlers/dns-monitoring/blob/master/lambda_src/main.py) for myself.